# Asp.Net mvc - accessing IoC container from Session_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I want to manage my auth cookies similar to http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

I'd like to check the cookie on session start, auth the user if there is one and exchange it for a new one on the start of each new session. I'd also like to create one if none exist.

This is to take care of the 'remember me' type functionality - similar to how SO works.

To do this I need to be able to pull services from the container from within the Session_Start method in the global.asax. While debugging the app I step through the Application_Start method where the container is constructed. Everything goes OK and the Container property of the global.asax is created. But when I step into the Session_Start - the Container is null.

Is there something happening that I'm not aware of? Is there a better way to be doing this?

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            Container = new WindsorContainer().AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
                .Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("Configuration\\Windsor.config"))
                .Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "SonaTribe*.dll")));


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// See http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Container != null)
            {
                var accountService = Container.Resolve<IAccountService>();
                var logger = Container.Resolve<ILogger>();
                var forms = Container.Resolve<IFormsAuthentication>();

                // if there is a cookie
                if (Context.Request.Cookies["user-id"] != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //get the new cookie key from the server
                        var newUserSessionResponse = accountService.RegisterNewUserSession(new RegisterNewUserSessionRequest
                        {
                            SessionId = Context.Request.Cookies["user-id"].Value
                        });

                        if (newUserSessionResponse.Success)
                        {
                            //do something
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Info("Failed attaching the user to the session", newUserSessionResponse.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        logger.Error("Failed attaching the user to the session", exc);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //new user:
                   //do things
                } 
            }
        }
```

Thanks

w://

Comment: What *container* are you using?

Comment: Add a little source to help us understand what you're doing in these methods.

Comment: how are you storing the container and then pulling it in Session_Start() ?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't show where the container is stored.

Comment: Hi Mauricio - this is a global.asax in an asp.net mvc application that implements the Castle.Windsor.IContainerAccessor so it's a public IWindsorContainer with a private setter on the MvcApplication class.

Comment: Is the container stored in a static variable? See http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=233 for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing IContainerAccessor it's standard practice to store the container as a static variable of the global HttpApplication. See http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=233 for reference.

If you don't use a static variable, the container will be lost when the ASP.NET runtime disposes the HttpApplication (the runtime internally maintains a pool of HttpApplication instances).

Answer (score 0):

Move (the declaration of) Container into a static class and make sure it (Container) is static.

Comment: I have tried this and while I can now access the container from the session_start method - i'm sure there must be negative connotations related to making the container static?